# Using Atom as default editor for Factor listener

Tags: atom-editor, factor-lang

I'd like to use Atom as my default editor for the Factor listener, so that typing `\ foo edit` will open the definition of `foo` in Atom. But when I try it, I get this instead:

```
Launching failed with error:
Win32 error 0x2: The system cannot find the file specified.
Launch descriptor:

T{ process
    { command
        {
            "atom"
            "C:\\path\\to\\factor_directory\\Factor/work/file_directory/filename.factor:1"
        }
    }
    { detached t }
    { environment H{ } }
    { environment-mode +append-environment+ }
    { group +same-group+ }
}
```

But if I cd into directory and execute `atom filename.factor` from powershell (I'm on Windows 8.1), it works fine, which suggests there is something wrong with the command generated by Factor. So I opened `C:\path\to\factor_directory\Factor\basis\editors\atom` and found

```
! Copyright (C) 2014 Doug Coleman.
! See http://factorcode.org/license.txt for BSD license.
USING: editors kernel make math.parser namespaces sequences ;
IN: editors.atom

SINGLETON: atom-editor
atom-editor \ editor-class set-global

SYMBOL: atom-path

M: atom-editor editor-command ( file line -- command )
    [
        atom-path get "atom" or ,
        number>string ":" glue ,
    ] { } make ;
```

I have the vaguest idea about how this works. I guess I should change the definition of `editor-command` in some way, but I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The atom executable probably isn't in your path.  If you look at the following line:

```
atom-path get "atom" or ,
```

The `or` word takes 2 items from the stack, and if one of them is true, it will output the first of which, otherwise, `f` (false) is returned (if you are using the GUI listener, you can actually look up documentation for a specific word in the Help Browser interactively by clicking on the word itself! So you can click on `or` and read the documentation to figure out how it works).

Looking at the error message, `"atom"` is being returned, so we can deduce that

```
atom-path get
```

Must have returned `f` (false).  So what you need to do is to set the editor's executable path to `atom-path` before executing the `edit` word:

```
"C:/path/to/atom.exe" \ atom-path set-global
```

Now I'm not certain if the path delimiter I used would work as-is in Windows, but you get the idea.

Comment: You can use "/" or "\\" for path delimiter, both work in windows, and I think other OSes too.